# How to use a loop to print out data from a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I was wondering how you could use a loop (maybe a while-loop och for) to print out data for all the object in a list. **NOTE** that the data is from a textfile that I have saved to a list.

If we have a list with object and they contain data like:

> Australia/AU/36/8177/22919
> Austria/AT/40/6936/8429
>
> Azerbaijan/AZ/31/2896/9421
>
> Bahamas/BS/44/79/351

how can I use a loop of somekind to print out the data (from a textfile) for all the objects in the list?

Comment: Is this actually a list. Meaning its in the form myList=['Australia/AU/36/8177/22919', 'Austria/AT/40/6936/8429', 'Azerbaijan/AZ/31/2896/9421 ', 'Bahamas/BS/44/79/351']?

Comment: No its data from a textfile. But assume that I have split the strings and createt a object to append to my list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
your_list = [
    'Australia/AU/36/8177/22919',
    'Austria/AT/40/6936/8429',
    'Azerbaijan/AZ/31/2896/9421'
    'Bahamas/BS/44/79/351'
]

for element in your_list:
    print element
```

Ah, I hope now I understand you. You split each line at the `'/'` character, right? Something like this?

```
your_list = []
with open('your_file.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        your_list.append(line.strip().split('/'))

for sublist in your_list:
    print sublist
```

Comment: Yes my data is in a textfile which I have split and added to a list

Comment: """print "\n".join(your_list)"""
Will be much faster than looping over a list and calling print individually. And for printing a file """print fobj.read()"""

Comment: @PeterStahl assume that I have saved my data from a textfile to a list first. How do I do then?

Comment: @PeterStahl There isnt any problem I just want to know if I have some data in a textfile and than save it to a list, by spliting each elements and making a object of it to append to a list. How do i print out the data for all the objects in the list.

Comment: @John What do you mean by *object*? So you have a list of strings? And what do you consider an *element*? A single line from your text file? Please be more specific.

Comment: @PeterStahl No I have a list of elements that used to be just a string. Like in my example above with the countires and the numbers. Example: Australia/AU/36/8177/22919 is just a string. Then i split it to make elements in a list. And i did this for all of the data in my textfile.

Comment: @pyInTheSky Are you sure it's faster? If the list has elements already pushing the machine's RAM, or the file won't fit into memory - it's also likely to break :)

Comment: @John At which character do you split your data? Look at my edited post. Is this what you mean? Unless you speak more clearly and show us some code, I'm out now.

Comment: @John You do it in the way I've shown above. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @John It is much much faster, especially with lots of text or writing a block of data back to a file. do a timeit on the following data set as an example """data = map(str,range(1000000))""" (2-20 tims faster depending on the data)